# Hook foreground window

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can i hook the foreground window?

Currently I'm trying with

```
using (Process processTmp = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
  using (ProcessModule module = processTmp.MainModule)
  {
    IntPtr hModule = Win32.GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);
    uint threadid = Win32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(Win32.GetForegroundWindow(), IntPtr.Zero);

    //WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4
    m_HookId = Win32.SetWindowsHookEx(4, m_HookProcedure, hModule, threadid); 
    if (m_HookId == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      int tmp =
        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
  }
}
```

But m_HookID is always IntPtr.Zero with error 1428 - Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle(ERROR_HOOK_NEEDS_HMOD).
So it seems that there is something wrong with hModule.

Any suggestions?
Tnx.

Comment: Your first problem is that you are trying to inject a hook with managed code. This injects the CLR into every process, which can create problems since a process cannot host two conflicting versions of the CLR. If any process you want to hook is also using managed code, there may be a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot inject a managed assembly into a process.  A native DLL is required, written in a language like C, C++ or Delphi.  [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx) might be useful as a source for the DLL you'll need.